# what will be the time when temperature reach $30◦ C$?

Tags: exponential-function

> > Assume that the rate at which a body cools is proportional to the difference in temperature between the body and its surroundings. A body is heated to $110◦C$ and is placed in air at $10◦C$. After one hour, its temperature is $60◦C.$ At what time will its temperature reach $30◦C$?

My attempt :By the formula  $$T(t)-T(s)=(T(0)-T(s))e^{-kt}$$

$\color{orange}{\text{Given condition}}$: It takes $t=60\ minutes $ for temperature fall $\color{red}{110^\circ \ C \to 60^\circ \ C}$

Setting the corresponding values, final temperature $T(t)=60^\circ\ C$ , initial temperature $T(0)=110^\circ\ C$ & surrounding body temperature $T(s)=10^\circ\ C$  we get    $$60-10=(110-10)e^{-k(60)}$$

$$e^{-k}=\frac{1}{2}$$
$$-60k=\log(\frac{1}{2})$$
$$k=-\log(\frac{1}{2})=\log 2\tag 1$$

Now, for temperature fall $\color{red}{110^\circ \ C \to 30^\circ \ C}$ , setting $T(t)=30^\circ \ C$, $T(0)=110^\circ\ C$ & $T(s)=10^\circ\ C$ we get 
$$30-10=(110-10)e^{-kt}$$
$$e^{-kt}=\frac{20}{100}=\frac{1}{5}$$
$$\implies -kt=\ln\left(\frac{1}{5}\right)$$
Setting the value of $k$ from (1), we get time $t$ as follows
$$t \log 2=-\frac{1}{5}$$

that is $$t= \frac{\log 5}{\log 2} Hrs $$

Is my answer is correct or not ?

Comment: Incidentally, this question may also be appropriate for [Physics Stack Exchange](https://physics.stackexchange.com). Apart from that, methinks your method is correct :)

Comment: i edit its check my answer@trancelocation is its correct ?

Comment: At $(1)$ ther is $60$ missing.

Comment: im taking hrs @trancelocation 1hrs =60 minute

Comment: Ah. Overlooked this, because at the beginning you state $t=60min$. But if the time unit is hours, your result is correct.

Comment: thanks u sir @trancelocation

Comment: I give you another short answer without calculating that much. Will write it now. Your problem can be seen as a so called half time problem, which make it quicker to be solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your result is correct. But I thought it could be helpful to show a short cut.

- The starting model is $T(t) = 10 + 100e^{-kt}$.
- After $1$ hour $T(1)= 60 \Leftrightarrow 50 = 100\cdot \color{blue}{\frac 12}$
- $\Rightarrow t_o = 1$ is the $\color{blue}{halftime}$ of the cooling process
  $$\Rightarrow T(t) = 10+100\cdot 2^{-t}\Rightarrow 30 = 10+100\cdot 2^{-t}$$
  $$\Leftrightarrow \frac 15 = 2^{-t} \Rightarrow t=\log_2 5 $$
  ($t$ measured in hours)